# C network server programming on linux

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I would like to make program so that, when client disconnected, the server will back ready to accept a new request from client. Here is the code

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXLINE 100
#define LISTENQ 10

int main()
{
    int tmp, listenfd, connfd;
    int sin_size;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
    char  buff[MAXLINE];
    time_t ticks;
    while(true)
    {
        bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
        servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        servaddr.sin_port        = htons(13);
        memset(&(servaddr.sin_zero),'\0',8);
        listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(listenfd == -1){
           perror("error socket");
           exit(1);
          }

        tmp=bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        if(tmp == -1){
            perror("error bind..");
            exit(1);
        }

        tmp=listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);
        if(tmp == -1){
            perror("error listen"); 
            exit(1);
        }

        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);    
        connfd=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &sin_size);
        if(connfd == -1){
            perror("error accept"); 
            exit(1);
        }

        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(buff,sizeof(buff),"Now Time: %.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
        write(connfd, buff, strlen(buff));
        close(connfd);
        close(listenfd);
    }
}
```

I found a problem on this part

```
tmp=bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'socklen_t* {aka unsigned int*}' [-fpermissive]

```
connfd=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &sin_size);
```

error: initializing argument 3 of 'int accept(int, sockaddr*, socklen_t*)' [-fpermissive]

What should I do with those problem? Didn't the pointer right?

Comment: That's a pretty comprehensible error message.

Comment: declare `sin_size` as `socklen_t`. also, remember to `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: @user4815162342 do you mean declare sin_size as socklen_t like this "int sin_size socklen_t" ?

Comment: The code misses to check the return value of `write()`.

Comment: This line `memset(&(servaddr.sin_zero),'\0',8);` is useless as you already used `bzero` on `servaddr`. Also it's dangerous as you cannot be sure `sin_zero` will be 8 bytes wide. Also using "magic" numbers (`8`) is at least bad style.

Comment: @greenthunder change line 16 to socklen_t sin_size; should be ok and that's all.

Comment: Small things: `bzero` is deprecated, use `memset`. Don't use for example `sockaddr_in`, use `sockaddr_storage` (etc) to make life easier for yourself or other people when the need for `IPv6` gets real.

Comment: You should have some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) or at least use a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
socklen_t sin_size;
```

Comment: I changed that, and the result is still error bind from here "tmp=bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))"

Comment: Just use the `sin_size` which you just fixed to be of proper type.

Answer (score 1):

Chnage your declaration

```
 socklen_t  sin_size;
```

This solves your issue.

---

<s>you can also Try this as last resort but above change would works fine for you.</s>

<s>Modify this statement</s>

<s>connfd=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,(socklen_t * ) &sin_size);</s>

See `man accept`

After seeing @alk comment i am adding this part from comment.

Especially when casting pointers, it might just cast away an compile-time error but very well might crash when running as the sizes of what the program expects when Dereferencing the pointer differs from reality.

Comment: Why do you advise to cast, if the most straight forward solution would be to declare `sin_size` to be `socklen_t`? Casting should always be used as last resort.

Comment: Indeed.this should be last resort. I was added this answer as optional.

Comment: And especailly when casting pointers, it might just cast away an compile-time error but very well might crash when running as the sizes of what the program expects when dereferencing the pointer differs from reality. You'd better delete this part of your answer.

Comment: thanks for neat explanation. I have come across this issue. In OP case, did not get any issue but really better to remove that from answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `while(1)` instead of `while(true)` and use a C-compiler instead of a C++-compiler.

The errors come from compiling the source code with a C++compiler. If you use a C-Compiler your code does not produce the mentioned errors, except that now `true` is not defined.

Comment: thanks for remembered me.. but it still got an error said "$demo
error bind..: Permission denied" what should I do then? I already changed while (true) to while(1) and keep the rest

Comment: @greenthunder: You need to have root rights to bind to ports below 1024.

Comment: Your answer somehow does not anser the OP's question. It show btter be a comment.

Comment: In what respect doesn't this answer the question *What should I do with those problem?*

Comment: @alk how to bind to ports below 1024?

Comment: @greenthunder: Run the process under a user account having root rights.

Comment: Please excuse, but I really do not see any relation betwee your answer and those two errors which clearley due to `sin_size` being delcared as `int` but `socklen_t`.

Comment: Ok, I see. The C compiler just throws warnings but errors, as the C++ would do. You are right. But thats a subtile fix, indeed.

Comment: @alk is that all? thank you so much for teaching newbie like me :)

Comment: C99 has a `bool` type, with `true` and `false`.

Comment: @BrianCain They are still undefined unless `#include <stdbool.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer, need to run on root-access user

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAXLINE 100
#define LISTENQ 10

int main()
{
    int tmp, listenfd, connfd;
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
    char  buff[MAXLINE];
    time_t ticks;
    while(true)
    {
        bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
        servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        servaddr.sin_port        = htons(13);
        memset(&(servaddr.sin_zero),'\0',8);
        listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(listenfd == -1){
           perror("error socket");
           exit(1);
          }

        tmp=bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        if(tmp == -1){
            perror("error bind..");
            exit(1);
        }

        tmp=listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);
        if(tmp == -1){
            perror("error listen"); 
            exit(1);
        }

        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);    
        connfd=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &sin_size);
        if(connfd == -1){
            perror("error accept"); 
            exit(1);
        }

        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(buff,sizeof(buff),"Sekarang pukul: %.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
        write(connfd, buff, strlen(buff));
        close(connfd);
        close(listenfd);
    }
}
```